Telegram bot удаление сообщения с эффектом растворения
Не могу найти в API метод удаления сообщения, когда сообшение растворяется (буквально), а после этого выводится новое сообщение. Уже несколько дней ищу и без результата.

В aiogram вы можете использова bot.edit_message() и еще несколько методов для редактирования media и остальных типов сообщений, чтобы увидеть все методы, попробуйте набрать bot.edit_ в редакторе и он покажет доступные методы или обратитесь к документации по запросу edit_message.

скорее мне нужен метод удаления сообщения с эффектом растворения

Насколько я помню, метод call.message.delete() именно так и удаляет сообщения, отдельного метода для удаления с растворением нет, когда вы в чате и наблюдаете за сообщением, оно как раз и удаляется с неким эффектом растворения.
